# Unable to validate account confirmation in WSO2 version 6.0

Tags: wso2-identity-server

When I'm validating the account by clicking the link given in email during account verification process(sign up process), I'm getting below error. Can you please suggest what is causing this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkJHu.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the self-registration config section, there is a configuration for callback validation. It is provided as a regex. Make sure you have configured it properly.

[image]