# Callback url value in email for verifying account

Tags: wso2-identity-server

This is an extension of [Unable to validate account confirmation in WSO2 version 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73803969/unable-to-validate-account-confirmation-in-wso2-version-6-0) issue.
I have same regex pattern in my self-registration section. But when I'm creating users using rest API, the link which I got in the email is

```
https://localhost:9443/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmregistration.do?confirmation=ce790759-1086-4870-a673-35b5927351d8&userstoredomain=PRIMARY&username=samyu&tenantdomain=carbon.super&callback={{callback}}
```

and when I created the user using manually the link which I got is

```
https://localhost:9443/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmregistration.do?confirmation=dff024e7-d7e7-48ef-bb60-1c1c4d6f3b1c&userstoredomain=PRIMARY&username=sam&tenantdomain=carbon.super&callback=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2Fmyaccount.
```

So, the difference between these two links is that callback. So what configuration should I make in order to get the callback value

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying this from the recovery portal, the callback value is set automatically. If you are trying with the REST API you need to include that in the request. The following is a sample JSON payload.

```
{
"user": {
    "username": "kim",
    "realm": "PRIMARY",
    "password": "Password12!",
    "claims": [
        {
            "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/givenname",
            "value": "kim"
        },
        {
            "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress",
            "value": "kimAndie@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/lastname",
            "value": "Anderson"
        },
        {
            "uri": "http://wso2.org/claims/mobile",
            "value": "+947729465558"
        }
    ]
},
"properties": [
    {
        "key": "callback",
        "value": "https://localhost:9443/myaccount"
    }
]
}
```

Notice the way how you need to send the callback when using the REST API.